# Index is not work on empty string with where clause in mysql db

Tags: mysql, indexing, where-clause, query-performance

The index is not working on an empty string with a where clause in mysql.

```
select x,y  from z   where y =''
```

The index is already created on column y. and i have 60% data with empty string in column y

Comment: Please, *please,* read this and then [edit] your question.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Pay particular attention to the section on query performance.  How do you know the index is not used? How many rows are in your table? Is it possible that, given your `WHERE` clause hits 60% of your table, that the query planner decided a table scan take less CPU and IO than the index scan would?

Comment: The empty string and `NULL` are different.  Perhaps you need `WHERE y IS NULL`?